# two chrono durations through a ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11

If i have tw `std::chrono::duration`s applied as source operators of a ternary operator, why is the duration with the larger resolution returned ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    auto dur = true ? 0ms : 0s;
    cout << typeid(dur).name() << endl;
}
```

For me this prints ...

```
class std::chrono::duration<__int64,struct std::ratio<1,1000> >
```

... with MSVC.

With built-in types the compiler kows what's the common type of both values, but how does the compiler know that if there are two durations ?

I further elaborated this issue. It was unclear to me whether the ternary operator relies on common_type (if accessible). So I wrote some code to test if the ternary operator is aware of common_type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct X {};

struct A
{
    operator X() { return X(); };
};

struct B
{
    operator X() { return X(); };
};

template<>
struct common_type<A, B>
{
    using type = X;
};

int main()
{
    cout << typeid(common_type_t<A, B>).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(true ? A() : B()).name() << endl;
}
```

The code doesn't compile because of the second line in main(). The compiler says that the operands are incompatible, so defining a common type for A and B doesn't help. So why does the ternary operator work for different durations anyway ?

Comment: Because that's how the ternary operator works. It's an expression, and an expression has a single type, determined at compile time.  One of the two values gets converted to the type of the other.

Comment: `std::chrono::milliseconds` [is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) as duration holding at least 45 bits, so quite expected that int64 was selected by your compiler?

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: When searching for a common type, `<chrono>` only considers lossless conversions. Since the conversion from milliseconds to seconds involves potential loss of data, it is not considered. The only other alternative is a conversion from seconds to milliseconds, which is never lossy (unless it overflows), so that is the one that is chosen. You can see the same thing with addition: `0ms + 0s`.

Answer (score 2):

This part is not a duplicate:

> With built-in types the compiler kows what's the common type of both values, but how does the compiler know that if there are two durations ?

The conversions among `duration` are designed such that one `duration` can implicitly convert to another [only if the conversion is exact](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.cons#3).

Your use of the phrase "common type" maps to the library trait `std::common_type`.  And more generally given:

```
auto x = true ? a : b;
```

Then `decltype(x)` is the `common_type` of `decltype(a)` and `decltype(b)`.  So understanding `common_type` for `duration`s is helpful.

`common_type` is specialized for `duration` [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.traits.specializations).

```
template<class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2>
  struct common_type<chrono::duration<Rep1, Period1>,
                     chrono::duration<Rep2, Period2>>
{
    using type = chrono::duration<common_type_t<Rep1, Rep2>, see below>;
};
```

It is formed by the `common_type` of the two `Rep`s.  And here is the interesting part:  by the greatest common divisor of `Period1` and `Period2`.

One can find the greatest common divisor of a fraction by taking the greatest common divisor of the two numerators and dividing that by the least common multiple of the two denominators, as explained in [this note](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.traits.specializations#note-1).

This is a complicated definition, but it boils down to fairly simple English:  The `common_type` of two `duration`s will be the coarsest `duration` that both argument `duration`s will implicitly convert to.  The English is a simplification of the actual definition but is correct enough to answer this question.

Note also that with integral-based `duration`s that implicit conversion is only allowed when the conversion is lossless (exact).

For example `seconds` will implicitly convert to `milliseconds`, but not vice-versa.  Because `milliseconds` can always hold the exact value of `seconds`.  Therefore with `seconds` and `milliseconds`, `milliseconds` is the coarsest `duration` that both `seconds` and `milliseconds` will implicitly convert to.  Thus `milliseconds` is the `common_type` of `seconds` and `milliseconds`.

For the predefined `duration` units that are as fine or finer than `weeks`, the `common_type` of two of them is always the one with the finer precession.

```
weeks  // C++20
days   // C++20
hours
minutes
seconds
milliseconds
microseconds
nanoseconds
```

Choose any two and the `common_type` is the lower one in this list.

For other units things can get more complicated.  The `common_type` of two `duration`s can even be a third `duration` type.  For example the `common_type` of `years` and `days` is a `duration` with a period of 216s.   And sure enough, both `years` and `days` will exactly convert to this unit.  And no `duration` with a larger period exists which both `years` and `days` will exactly convert to.

Comment: So the ternary operator is ware of the trait common_type ?

Comment: It is more the opposite:  `common_type` is aware of the conditional operator: http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#trans.other-4.3.3.  The conditional operator works based on the converting duration constructors.  But `common_type` really explains the big picture behind duration conversions.

Comment: To make the whole thing work the ternary operator must be aware of the common_type in the first place. This is what I asked for.

Comment: No, the ternary operator is not aware of `common_type`. For example, `true ? days{0} : years{0}` is invalid, because `std::chrono::years` cannot be converted implicitly to `std::chrono::days`, nor can it the other way around. But your example works, because `std::chrono::seconds` can be converted implicitly to `std::chrono::milliseconds`. It's all about implicit conversions, not `common_type`.

Comment: And why is there a specialization of common_type if the compiler can determine the "common type" for the ternary operator ? Why doesn't the non-specialized declaration of common_type help then ?

Comment: `std::common_type<DA, DB>` has a superset of the functionality required by the conditional operator, namely the ability to (in some cases) name a third type `DC`.  And this is needed in some "mixed mode" duration expressions such as the addition of quarter seconds and one-third seconds resulting in one-twelfth seconds.